# How to add and remove extender on runtime?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am using extender for validation in the text-box to accept only numeric value. I had referred the same example as shown in [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) link, 
but in my case I have a drop-down beside text-box, for particular selected text of drop-down it should apply  this binding(with extender) otherwise it should apply normal binding.

For few options of dropdown, textbox should apply numeric check for others it should not.

I want to change these two binding on drop-down change on run-time -

```
self.TextInput = ko.observable(); 
self.TextInputNumeric = ko.observable().extend({ numeric: 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my question here, on the bottom there are a couple of edits with actual code that may help 
you

[Move validation from observable to computed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119826/move-validation-from-observable-to-computed)